# Confused about app icons folders

Tags: 12.04, icons, elementary

Actually, there are at least 4 or 5 folders where icons are stored! I'm confused. I never liked those linux folders organization when you are the only, and begginer user.

I would like to change/add app icons, for example, when a scalable one isn't provided. However I have to dig into these directories, because some `.desktop` app files just gives the name of the app assuming the OS knows where to find them.

```
/usr/share/icons

/usr/share/pixmaps

/usr/local/share/icons

/usr/local/{app-name}/icons/hicolor/scalable

~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/{size}/apps/
```

In pixmaps folder I found icons in .xpm format. They are usually 16x16 or 32x32. However there are apps which seems to have scalable ones somewhere.

Comment: Now there is also `/usr/share/app-install/icons/` …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the application starter file (`.desktop`) of the application you are interested in.

Lets say I want to find the icon of Firefox. The desktop file is located at `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`.

Drag the desktop file into your text editor and find the name of the icon it uses:

[image: Editing the firefox.desktop file]

Note the line `Icon=firefox`. This implicitly says the icon's file name is `firefox.png`.

Almost all the icon themes are stored at `/usr/share/icons`. Very few programs will put their icons in `/usr/share/pixmaps`  Those are the two directories usually the operating system will seek for the icon file, in order.

Since we want to find `firefox.png` I'll open up my Terminal and execute the command:

```
find /usr/share -iname "firefox.png"
```

Result:

[image: List of firefox.png files found beneath /usr/share]

As you can see the icon we seek is `/usr/share/pixmaps/firefox.png`
The path depends on the icon theme you use. The icon sizes most application launchers tend to use are `64x64`, `128x128` or `256x256`. It depends.

You might also want to read [freedesktop.org standard icon lookup method](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html).

Comment: thanks! That's a nice way. I wonder why it isn't easier. I mean, the user has to **track down** where the icon is.

Comment: Trust me, you will find it easier when you get around with the system. You necessarily do not need to track the icon. Just think the way that you would find the icon if you are the operating system. First check `/usr/share/icon/curent_theme/256` if not found look in `/usr/share/pixmaps` :)